# Question about "weird" transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For polynomials $\mathcal P_2(\Bbb R)$ the transformation $\psi$ is defined as follows:

$$\psi:\mathcal P_2(\Bbb R)\rightarrow\mathcal P_2 (\Bbb R), \space \space (\psi p)(t)=-t^2\cdot \frac{d^2p(t)}{dt^2}+t \cdot \frac{d p(t)}{dt}$$

1. Prove that $\psi$ is a $\Bbb R$-linear transformation
2. Calculate ker($\psi$), img($\psi$) and dim($\psi$)
3. Find a transformation matrix $M_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal B}(\psi)$ with respect to $\mathcal B=${$1,t,t^2$}

This is what I have tried so far:

1. In order for a transformation to be linear it needs to satisfy $T(a+b)=T(a)+T(b)$ and $T(\lambda a)=\lambda T(a)$. I wasn't sure what a "$\Bbb R$-linear" transformation is. Is it just a normal linear transformation?

$$\begin{align} (\psi p)(a+b)&=-(a+b)^2\cdot \frac{d^2p(a+b)}{dt^2}+(a+b) \cdot \frac{d p(a+b)}{dt} \\
& = -(a^2+2ab+b^2) \cdot (\frac{d^2 p(a)}{dt^2}+\frac{d^2 p(b)}{dt^2})+(a+b) \cdot (\frac{d p(a)}{dt}+\frac{d p(b)}{dt} ) \\
& = -(a^2+2ab+b^2)\frac{d^2 p(a)}{dt^2}-(a^2+2ab+b^2)\frac{d^2 p(b)}{dt^2}+a\frac{d p(a)}{dt}+b\frac{d p(b)}{dt} \\
&\not = (\psi p)(a)+(\psi p)(b) \end{align}$$

Am I doing something wrong here? The transformation seems to violate the first criterion.

2. Is it true that in order to determine ker($\psi$) I need to solve this equation: 
   $$-t^2 \frac{d^2p(t)}{dt^2}+t\frac{d p(t)}{dt}=0$$

for $t$?

Is there some way to show that this mapping is surjective? (sort of the easy way to determine the image)

3. I have no idea what to do here. Maybe someone can give me a hint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $a,b$ ought be polynomials, not scalars

Comment: For the first part, the transformation is a map from polynomials to polynomials so it's linear in polynomials. That is $\psi(p+q)=\psi p+\psi q$ for polynomials $p,q$.

Comment: Yeah I totally missed that. Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb R$-linear just means linear where the scalars come from $\mathbb R$. A transformation could also be $\mathbb Q$-linear, $\mathbb C$-linear, etc.

Comment: Hint: $\psi(at^2+bt+c)=-t^2\cdot 2a+t\cdot(2a+b)=bt$. This is linear. The kernel is $at^2+c$, the image $bt$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. Why is the image $bt$? How did you arrive at that?

Comment: Hem, $\psi(at^2+bt+c)=bt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you're wrong. I think you misinterpreted the transformation: $t$ is the variable, not the polynomial being transformed. Your computation should begin with:
$$\psi(a+b)=-t^2\frac{\mathrm d^2(a+b)}{\mathrm d t^2}+t\frac{\mathrm d(a+b)}{\mathrm d t}=\dotsm $$
Any way $\psi$ is a linear combination of first and second derivatives (which are linear transformations) with coefficients in the polynomial ring, so that it is linear.

2) Yes. Set $p(t)=at^2+bt+c$, whence $p'(t)=2at+b$, $p''(t)=2a$.
$$p(t)\in\ker\psi\iff -2at^2 +t(2at+b)=bt=0\iff b=0.$$
Thus $p(f))\in \ker\psi$ if and only if $p(t)$ has no linear term.

3) Compute $\psi(1), \psi(t), \psi(t^2)$ and use the results as the vector-columns of the matrix of $\psi$.

Comment: $t$ is also a polynomial

Comment: Thanks! Don't I also need to plug the functions $a(t), b(t)$ into $-t^2$?

Comment: Isn't "linear combination" usually referred for combining vectors (or linear transformations) via scalars? In this case $t^2$ and $t$ are polynomials (not scalars) so saying that $\psi$ is a linear combination of first and second derivatives doesn't seem to be appropriate.

Comment: @SuH: On the contrary.

Comment: @Anurag: You're certainly right. I thought to all this stuff as elements in a $\mathbf R[t]$-module, which  is a $\mathbf R$-vector space by restriction of scalars. But this isn't very rigourous.

Comment: I have another question. For 2. Do I need to find the values of $t$ that satisfy the equation $-t^2p''(t)+tp(t)=0$ or the solutions to the second order differential equation $p(t)$?

Comment: It is the second solution. But you don't have to find the general solution: you only solve in quadratic polynomials. Note you can factor out $t$ in the equation

Comment: @Bernard I will try my best. Can I ask you again in case I am not getting anywhere?

Comment: There's no problem.

Comment: Okay I have to ask again. How do you solve this "in quadratic polynomials". I have only solved diff. equations to get general solutions. When I solve it in mathematica I get some really akward solution containing the Bessel function.

Comment: Bessel functions are for the general solution of the differential equation. Her we only seek for quadratic polynomials, and it' much more simple. See my updated answer.

Comment: That was indeed much simpler than what I was doing. Thank again for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

For linearity this is how you should check:

Let $a(t), b(t) \in \mathcal P_2(\Bbb R)$, then you need to verify if 
$$\psi(a(t)+b(t))=\psi(a(t))+\psi(b(t)).$$
For example, the left side should be interpreted as
$$\psi(a(t)+b(t))=-t^2\cdot \frac{d^2}{dt^2}[a(t)+b(t)]+t \cdot \frac{d }{dt}[a(t)+b(t)]$$

Comment: Thanks! Makes much more sense now. Any ideas regarding 2. and 3.?

Answer (score 1):

$P_2$ is the set of polynomials of degree at most $2$, so it is the set of polynomials $ax^2+bx+c$.  In the basis, that would be represented as $(c,b,a)^t$.
Calculate $\psi(ax^2+bx+c)$; represent that as a vector; and find what matrix sends $(c,b,a)^t$ to the new vector.

Comment: Thankyou! I didn't know what $\mathcal P_2$ meant so I was just about to ask. This clears up a lot of my misunderstandings. Why is it $(c,b,a)^T$ and not $(a,b,c)^T$?

Comment: Oops. Please ignore my last comment. I seem to have forgotten matrix multiplication...

Comment: So I treid to solve 3. with your hints. I got $\psi(ax^2+bx+c)=bx$. Therefore the matrix I am looking for is $(0,x,0)$ since $(0,x,0)\begin{pmatrix}c\\b\\a \end{pmatrix}=bx$. Is this correct? What is the meaning of this matrix?

Comment: $bx$ would be represented as $(0,b,0)^t$, so the matrix would be $[0,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,0]$